# Is there a shorthand syntax for using connection strings from the config file in Castle Windsor 3.0?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, castle-windsor, connection-string, ioc-container

I'm trying to wire up Windsor 3.0 to inject connection strings from my web.config file into my repository classes.

At the moment, I have this syntax:

```
container.Register(
  Component
    .For<IFooRepository>().ImplementedBy(SqlFooRepository)
    .DependsOn(
       Property
         .ForKey("sqlConnectionString")
         .Eq(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString)
    )
  )
)
```

Given this must be a fairly common use case, is there some syntactic shorthand in Windsor I can use to bypass the explicit call to ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't. IMHO it's not worth adding it to Windsor. You can easily write such a shorthand with an extension method:

```
public static class PropertyKeyExtensions {
    public static Property UsingConnectionString(this PropertyKey p, string name) {
        return p.Eq(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString);
    }
}
...

container.Register(
  Component
    .For<IFooRepository>().ImplementedBy(SqlFooRepository)
    .DependsOn(
       Property
         .ForKey("sqlConnectionString")
         .UsingConnectionString("foo"))
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Agree it's too narrow, too uncommon and too simple to do yourself to make it part of Windsor API

Comment: Good answer, nice explanation, and a very clean alternative solution. Thanks, Windsor gurus... you guys rock :)